# Use max function on dictionary with a conditional statement

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am programming a football table in which there is a function that gets the highest amount of points. these points are made up of no. of wins*3 + no. of draws. If there are two of the same, the one with the least draws wins.

Currently i am using a dictionary to store the teams class attributes such as the name and the total points. I am aware I can find the highest value by using the `max` function in python by iterating through the keys and values.

What i want to know is how should i return the one with the least wins if I have a seperate dictionary with the format name:losses?

**in shorthand, find the highest scoring team(s) and if there are two teams with the same points, return the one that has the least losses.**

```
def getWinner(classList):
    teamPoints = {}
    losses = {}
    for item in classList:
        teamPoints[item.getName()] = item.getPoints()
        losses[item.getName()] = item.getLosses()
    return max(teamPoints, key=teamPoints.get)
```

This code currently gets the highest score but correctly if there are two with the same points but different losses.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text. There is a `{}` button that should be used to format code samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's builtin `sorted` function with a custom `key` function as comparator. If you just wnat the first result, them, just pick the first element of the list.

```
def key(element):
   return (element["name"] , - element["losses"])

winner = sorted(results, key=key)[0]
```

(assuming "results" is a list with your dictionaries containing the entries for each team)